Magento 2 Remove Address Fields From Admin Create Order Form
Note: This is not a duplicate - I've searched for this and there is no specific answer to this question.
I needed to remove Name Prefix and Name Suffix fields from Customer Account. I created following 2 files under
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml
and changed visibility from true to false which means these fields are not longer showing when you create a new customer in admin panel.
However, when you create a new order and either select and existing customer or create a new customer, these fields are visible there and I can't seem to find any clue as to how I can remove these fields. Any help will be appreciated.

Here, you can use 2 approaches to remove the given fields, 1 is by CSS or 1 is by using plugin,
Using CSS
Modify sales_order_create_index.xml Layout
create the below file in your custom module

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="order_address_form">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="additional_classes" xsi:type="string">no-prefix no-suffix</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>

After this, you can add the CSS for no-prefix and no-suffix like this in your CSS file
.no-prefix .no-siffix {
display:none;
}

Using Plugin

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Form\DataProvider">
    <plugin name="remove_prefix_suffix" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddressDataProvider" />
</type>


app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddressDataProvider.php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class AddressDataProvider
{
    public function afterGetData($subject, $result)
    {
        if (isset($result['prefix'])) {
            unset($result['prefix']);
        }
        if (isset($result['suffix'])) {
            unset($result['suffix']);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

Let me know, if this is useful !!!
